# Grid using Tailwind CSS leaves too much space

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want my grid to be tighter. This is what it looks like now:

[image: screenshot]

My initial code is:

```html
<div class="grid grid-flow-col auto-cols-[repeat(auto-fit,_16.666666%)] gap-x-5 px-20 mt-28 mb-20 text-xs">
  content
</div>
```

I have tried using `auto-cols-max`, and this solves the spacing issue, but the grid content is no longer centered under the "Roadmap" title.

Comment: Please play the entire code

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FMDaqj5s

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a lesser gap than `gap-x-5` to reduce the space,

And you can use `items-center` and `justify-items-center` to center the grid items.

```
<div class="grid grid-flow-col auto-cols-[repeat(auto-fit,_16.666666%)] gap-x-2 px-20 mt-28 mb-20 text-xs justify-items-center items-center">
  content
</div>
```

Comment: it is reduced the space but not much. i have tried this before

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adjusting the height? maybe set height as h-1